# tmux error in conda environment: "create window failed: fork failed: No such file or directory"

Tags: conda, tmux

I've just created and activated a new conda environment on Mac OS (`conda create --name tmux; source activate tmux`) and installed tmux using `conda install -c conda-forge tmux`. So far so good, but then when I run `tmux` I get the error message `create window failed: fork failed: No such file or directory`. This is pretty mysterious to me and I haven't been able to find any info about what this issue is and how to fix. I do not have a `.tmux.conf` file. Here is the output from running `conda info`:

```
active environment : tmux                                                                                                                                 │
    active env location : /Users/me/miniconda3/envs/tmux                                                                                                  │    add new simulation code, updated method of coding introgression that has correct initial proportion, for thesis proposal
            shell level : 2                                                                                                                                    │~
       user config file : /Users/me/.condarc                                                                                                              │~
 populated config files :                                                                                                                                      │~
          conda version : 4.12.0                                                                                                                               │~
    conda-build version : not installed                                                                                                                        │~
         python version : 3.9.12.final.0                                                                                                                       │~
       virtual packages : __osx=10.13.6=0                                                                                                                      │~
                          __unix=0=0                                                                                                                           │~
                          __archspec=1=x86_64                                                                                                                  │~
       base environment : /Users/me/miniconda3  (writable)                                                                                                │~
      conda av data dir : /Users/me/miniconda3/etc/conda                                                                                                  │~
  conda av metadata url : None                                                                                                                                 │~
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64                                                                                           │~
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch                                                                                           │~
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64                                                                                              │~
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch                                                                                              │~
          package cache : /Users/me/miniconda3/pkgs                                                                                                       │~
                          /Users/me/.conda/pkgs                                                                                                           │~
       envs directories : /Users/me/miniconda3/envs                                                                                                       │~
                          /Users/me/.conda/envs                                                                                                           │~
               platform : osx-64                                                                                                                               │~
             user-agent : conda/4.12.0 requests/2.27.1 CPython/3.9.12 Darwin/17.7.0 OSX/10.13.6                                                                │~
                UID:GID : 511:20                                                                                                                               │~
             netrc file : None                                                                                                                                 │~
           offline mode : False                                                                                                                                │~
```

Here is the output from `conda list`:

```
# packages in environment at /Users/brogroh/miniconda3/envs/tmux:                                                                                              │~
#                                                                                                                                                              │~
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel                                                                                             │~
ca-certificates           2022.5.18.1          h033912b_0    conda-forge                                                                                       │~
libevent                  2.1.10               h7d65743_4    conda-forge                                                                                       │~
ncurses                   6.3                  h96cf925_1    conda-forge                                                                                       │~
openssl                   3.0.3                hfe4f2af_0    conda-forge                                                                                       │~
tmux                      3.2a                 h749c5dd_0    conda-forge
```

Comment: Cannot replicate. Please add minimal steps to arrive at error. Consider using a new environment. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have tried creating new environments. Steps to produce on my machine: `conda create --name tmux; source activate tmux; conda install -c conda-forge tmux; tmux` at which point I'm seeing the error message above

Comment: Okay, thanks for responding. Yeah that’s basically what I did also on MacOS, though with `conda activate` instead of `source activate`. So consider adding more details to the question body, like output from `conda info` and the `conda list` when the minimal test environment is activated.